# remove lines from file using linux command/script have multiple condition to remove a single line

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to remove line from file have below lines starting with # and have Apache/apache. Please find below file content which I want to manipulate and remove :

```
----------------------------------------------------------
# Apache configuration
# This is apache configuration
This is not Apache configuration
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this using Regex and sed.

This should do it:

```
sed -i '/^#.*[Aa]pache/ d' <filename>
```

Broken down it is:

- -i: Read file, make changes and write result back to file
- ^#: Line starting with #
- .*: Any number of characters in between
- [Aa]: Match both upper and lower case A/a
- pache: Match the rest of the word
- / d: delete any lines that match
- filename: file to edit in place

If you need the output to go to stdout, you could also do:

```
cat <filename> | sed '/^#.*[Aa]pache/ d'
```

I'd recommend learning to use regular expressions:
https://regexone.com/